# Ways to have exactly $n$ nominees out of $2n$ voters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> There are $2n$ voters, each write his name on a paper as the voter and the name of his nominee. How many ways there are such that there are exactly $n$ different nominees and each of the nominees has exactly two votes.

Attempt 1:

$\binom {2n} n \sum _{\text{k is even}}^ n \binom {2n-k} 2$

Choose the nominees and then each time choose two voters.

But this isn't a closed form, so:

Attempt 2:

Using generating functions, there are $2n$ different balls and $n$ bins and we want each bin to hold exactly two balls.

So the generating functions would be: $(\frac {x^2} 2)^n$, so the closed form of that would be: $\frac 1 2 2^n \cdot n! = 2^{n-1}n!$ ?

Comment: For the first attempt, I would use the product, rather than the sum.

Comment: @Michael because they all happen together?

Comment: Yes.  The first choice for the first pair has $2n-2\choose 2$ choices for the second pair.  So does the second choice for the first pair, and all of these are different.  So you multiply the number of choices for the first pair $2n\choose 2$ by $2n-2\choose 2$ to get the number of choices for the first two pairs put together.  Then, as you did, combine all the way down to the final pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Attempt 1 you should replace the $\sum$ by a $\prod$: One can select $n$ nominees from the list of $2n$ people in ${2n\choose n}$ ways. Order the chosen nominees alphabetically. The first nominee can choose his two voters in ${2n\choose 2}$ ways, then the second nominee can choose his two voters among the $2n-2$ left over voters in ${2n-2}$ ways, and so on. All in all we obtain
$$N={2n\choose n}{2n\choose 2}{2n-2\choose 2}{2n-4\choose 2}\cdots{2\choose 2}={(2n)!\cdot(2n)!\over n!\>n!\>2^n}$$
possibilities. Here it was assumed that any voter is allowed to vote for himself.